# react-native run-android command errors with java.lang.outofmemoryerror

Tags: java, android, react-native, terminal

I keep getting an out of memory error whenever I try and do `react-native run-android` from within Visual Studio code. I've also tried just using the standard windows terminal but I get the same thing.

I've been looking at trying to increase it but it doesn't seem to help:

I've run `javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "MaxHeapSize"` which gives me `268435456`

I then tried to increase it via 'configure java':
[image]

But when I run the command again I get the same number back for the heap size and if I try react-native run-android again, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the heapSize for your android app.
You can change the heapSize of the app in
 `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Set `android:largeHeap="true"` on application tag like this.

```
<application
  android:largeHeap="true"
```

Usually apps runs without setting largeHeap:true. Make sure your coding is right and not overfetching data or something like that, before changing to largeHeap and set largeHeap to true only if necessary.